# Excel extract substring by delimiter and add char

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerapps

I have some cells with strings where some text is divided by a symbol.

I'd like to extract substrings by a delimiter, trim eventual blank spaces, add the hashtag char before each string and then add a space between them.

So from this:
`text1, text2, text3, text4`
to
`#text1 #text2 #text3 #text4`.

How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,"#"&TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")))`, or use [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) if no access to `TEXTSPLIT()` yet.

Comment: thank you! how to use this also on powerapp with the matchall function?

Comment: In PowerApps, I assume you would want to nest the appropriate alternatives; [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-split), [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-trim) and [`Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate). If you must you can use a regular expression in the `MatchAll()` function, for example `\s*([^,]+)\s*(?:,|$)`

Comment: I never used PowerApps, but it looks that you can refer to the `SubMatches` property of the `MatchAll()` function and nest this inside `Concat()`. I assume this would work. That raises the question: are you using Excel or PowerApps? Please be clear and concise in your question.

Comment: Excel but i just realized i might need it on powerapp too :) thank you so much

Comment: Or using : ="#"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", "," #")